# SHAP: How to get feature importance for categorical variable?

Tags: python, shap

I am trying to use the SHAP for an ANN model interpretation. I found that when I using

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], backgournd, plot_type='bar')
```

For a categorical variable after dummy, the feature importance would be something like

```
CategoricalFeature_A=0.1
CategoricalFeature_B=0.3
CategoricalFeature_C=0.3
```

I am wondering is there any way I can directly get the feature importance of `CategoricalFeature` ?

Comment: I found a source that says I can just add all the dummy variables' SHAP value as the SHAP value of the categorical variable. Is that correct?

Comment: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/397#issuecomment-455728636

Answer (score 0):

You can compute SHAP values using [native interface of XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html) rendering the same data as your shap_values. I used one categorical value with 4 categories inside. This is until now the only way I found to keep data as category and not transform them into dummies while still display the corresponding SHAP values.

Hope this help you or others.

Best,
Arnaud